# Warnings after updating plugin

Tags: android-studio, plugins, warnings

After I updated the plugin and the level of my App I get these warnings

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'. 
Configuration 'androidTestApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.
Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.

How can I fix these??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the 'compile' by 'implementation' in the 'Build.Gradle' on module app.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!! I now just don't know why the countdown timer is not working anymore....since I did the update.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56984819/countdown-timer-on-toast-doesnt-work-anymore-after-android-update